# Pritunl Rest Api using Php

Tags: php, api, httprequest, vpn

Has anyone managed to access pritunl's api using php?
The guide provided from the source code https://github.com/pritunl/pritunl/blob/master/tools/test_pritunl.py has only python examples. 
If I try do read data, it works fine. But when I try to update or create a new entity I receive HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED

My code is:

```
public static function auth_request($method, $path, $data="")
        $BASE_URL   = env('PRITUNL_BASE_URL');
        $API_TOKEN  = env('PRITUNL_API_TOKEN');
        $API_SECRET = env('PRITUNL_API_SECRET');
        $auth_timestamp = strval(time());
        $auth_nonce = uniqid();
        $auth_array = array(
            $API_TOKEN,
            $auth_timestamp,
            $auth_nonce,
            strtoupper($method),
            $path,
        );
        if ($data) {
            array_push($auth_array, $data);
        }
        $auth_string = join("&", $auth_array);
        $auth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac(
            "sha256", $auth_string, $API_SECRET, true));
        $options = array(
            "http" => array(
                "header"  => array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Auth-Token: '.$API_TOKEN,
                    'Auth-Timestamp: '.$auth_timestamp,
                    'Auth-Nonce: '.$auth_nonce,
                    'Auth-Signature: '.$auth_signature
                ),
                "method"  => $method,
                "content" => $data,
            ),
            "ssl" => array(
                "allow_self_signed" => true,
                "verify_peer_name" => false,
            ),
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        return file_get_contents($BASE_URL.$path, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved removing the $data from $auth_array. 
This is my new code:

```
public static function auth_request($method, $path, $data="") {
    $BASE_URL   = env('PRITUNL_BASE_URL');
    $API_TOKEN  = env('PRITUNL_API_TOKEN');
    $API_SECRET = env('PRITUNL_API_SECRET');
    $auth_timestamp = strval(time());
    $auth_nonce = uniqid();
    $auth_array = array(
        $API_TOKEN,
        $auth_timestamp,
        $auth_nonce,
        strtoupper($method),
        $path,
    );

    $auth_string = join("&", $auth_array);
    $auth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac(
        "sha256", $auth_string, $API_SECRET, true));
    $options = array(
        "http" => array(
            "header"  => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Auth-Token: '.$API_TOKEN,
                'Auth-Timestamp: '.$auth_timestamp,
                'Auth-Nonce: '.$auth_nonce,
                'Auth-Signature: '.$auth_signature
            ),
            "method"  => $method,
            "content" => $data,
        ),
        "ssl" => array(
            "allow_self_signed" => true,
            "verify_peer_name" => false,
        ),
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    return file_get_contents($BASE_URL.$path, false, $context);
}
```